# DateTime Comparison with objects php

Tags: php, datetime-format

This may be the most simple question however i don't know to best aproach this

I have 2 dates to compare `$lp` & `now()`

```
$lp = $ur->getLastPost($usr) ?: new \DateTime('yesterday');
$tdiff = date_diff(strtotime($lp),strtotime('now'));
```

`$lp` can either be `2019-11-21 17:20:44` or an current `yesterday` time

I want to transform $lp in a unixtimestamp so I can see if the difference is bigger than 3600 seconds

My problem is that i can't use strtotime because `$lp` can be an object, hence the error `strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: `$lp->diff(new \DateTime('now'))`? Or, if you want the difference in seconds, `$lp->getTimestamp() - time()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must parse `datetime` to format of you `$lp`:

```
$date = new DateTime($ur->getLastPost($usr) ?: 'yesterday');
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

then you can use `date_diff` to get difference of dates.

```
print_r($date->diff(new \DateTime('now')));
```

see [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) and [`Datetime class`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: I have combined your answer with the comment above and it does what it has to :) Thank you both